# Hall and knight inequality question

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

If $a^2+b^2=1$ and $x^2+y^2=1$, show that $ax+by<1$

Comment: You would require more constraints since otherwise $a = x = 1$ and $b = y = 0$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Welcome  to Math.SE.  You can get a lot more help if you show your attempts and where you are stuck.

Comment: Make it $\cdots\le 1$. This is a very well-known inequality.

Comment: Erhhhmm does $\cos \varphi=a$, $\sin \varphi=b$, $\cos \theta=x$, $\sin \theta=y$, $ax+by=\cos(\varphi-\theta)$ helps? @ParasKumar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what you're looking for:$$1=(a^2+b^2)(x^2+y^2)=(ax+by)^2+(ay-bx)^2\geqslant (ax+by)^2\implies \vert ax+by\vert\leqslant 1$$

Answer (score 1):

You can assume $a=\cos m, b=\sin m$ and $x=\sin t,y=\cos t$
Thus $ax+by= \cos m\sin t+\sin m\cos t=\sin(m+t)\leqslant 1$

Comment: [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).